# In "Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire", why did Garraka delay attacking until apparently the next day, coming in with a "storm" from the ocean?

Tags: plot-explanation, ghostbusters-frozen-empire

After Garraka is released, an attack on the firehouse, and in particular its containment unit, is delayed until apparently the next day, after a "storm" comes in from the Atlantic ocean onto a beach. There are several likely out of universe reasons such as [Valorum's comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122370/in-ghostbusters-frozen-empire-why-did-garraka-delay-attacking-until-apparent#comment217853_122370) indicating building plot tension, and it also gave time to make preparations (e.g., Nadeem learning & practicing his pyrokinesis, Phoebe reconfiguring her proton pack with a brass-like alloy, etc.). However, I don't recall, or know of, any particular explanation for that long of a delay in universe (e.g., in the movie itself).

Nonetheless, one plausible reason was to build up strength first, such as by getting and putting back its horns, located in the [hidden brass-lined chamber where Nadeem's grandmother stored the orb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters:_Frozen_Empire#Plot), and also by [feeding upon negative emotions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters:_Frozen_Empire#Plot), as was explained earlier by Dr. Hubert Wartzki at the New York Public Library. However, that could have also all been done in the New York City area itself, unless perhaps Garraka went to the other side of the ocean, such as Europe, to access a considerably larger, relatively concentrated, number of people.

Alternatively, or in addition to the possibility above, since Garraka was imprisoned thousands of years ago while in an ancient human civilization, with this likely being somewhere around the middle East region, perhaps there was some business to deal with there first.

I checked Wikipedia's [Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters:_Frozen_Empire#Plot) plot section, Screenrant's [Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire's New Villain Garraka Explained By Director](https://screenrant.com/ghostbusters-frozen-empire-movie-villain-garraka-explained-gil-kenan/), Villians Wiki's [Garraka](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Garraka) and [Ghostbusters: Frozen Empire ending explained: your biggest questions answered](https://www.gamesradar.com/ghostbusters-frozen-empire-ending-explained/), but none of them provided any details about this.

Comment: Because it builds plot tension?

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for your suggestion. I agree that is a likely out of universe reason. I have added it to my question, as well as another such reason of giving time to make preparations. However, as I asked about "in the movie itself", I was looking for in universe reasons, which I've also made somewhat more explicit now.